# Reading Xml from an absolute path

Tags: wcf, silverlight, xmlreader, absolute-path

I need to access a remote Xml document from a WCF service.  Right now I have:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("path");
```

But since the Xml doc is elsewhere on our network I need to give the `XmlReader` an absolute path, as opposed to having it look deeper in the project folder.  How do I do this?  I've found surprisingly little information about this.  It seems like this should be a simple thing to do.  Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use overload that accepts Stream parameters as follows:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"\\computername\shared path"))
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fileStream))
{
    // perform your custom code with XmlReader
}
```

Please note that you need appropriate permission to open remote stream. In WCF service context you may need to use impersonation.